# POST Request works with Postman, but not with Guzzle

Tags: php, json, laravel, postman, guzzle

In my Laravel application, I periodically need to POST data to an API using Guzzle.

The API users a bearer token to authenticate, and requests and accepts raw json. To test, I accessed the API using Postman, and everything worked wonderfully.

Postman Headers:

```
Accept:application/json
Authorization:Bearer [token]
Content-Type:application/json
```

And Postman Body:

```
{
    "request1" : "123456789",
    "request2" : "2468",
    "request3" : "987654321",
    "name" : "John Doe"
}
```

Postman returns a 200, and a JSON object as a response.

Now, when I try the same with Guzzle, I get a 200 status code, but no JSON object gets returned. Here's my Guzzle implementation:

```
public function getClient($token)
{
    return new Client([
        'base_uri' => env('API_HOST'),
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    ]);
}

$post = $client->request('POST', '/path/to/api', [
    'json' => [
        'request1' => 123456789,
        'request2' => 2468,
        'request3' => 987654321,
        'name' => 'John Doe',
    ]
]);
```

Is there some trick to POSTing JSON with Guzzle? If not, is there a way to debug what's going on under the hood?

I cannot, for the life of me, understand what the difference is between the Postman POST and the Guzzle POST.

Comment: Guzzle 6? ... you are using json_decode($response->getBody()) to get the json out of your response?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `headers` config sections for headers, not the root level.

```
return new Client([
    'base_uri' => env('API_HOST'),
    'headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ],
]);
```